# Windows Phone Gesture Detection

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, touch, gesture

I'm creating a game where the player will use Drag gestures to "slash" an enemy, swiping their finger across the screen to kill them.

I have a feeling this should be easier than it is, but currently the code I have to detect this is:

```
while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
{
    GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
    if (gs.GestureType == GestureType.FreeDrag ||
        gs.GestureType == GestureType.HorizontalDrag ||
        gs.GestureType == GestureType.VerticalDrag)
    {
        Current_Start = gs.Position;
        Current_End = Current_Start + gs.Delta;
    }
    if (gs.GestureType == GestureType.DragComplete)
    {
        DragEnded = true;
    }
}
```

This isn't quite working, though. I need the two vectors of:

- Where the drag started
- Where the drag ended

What is wrong, and how would I get this to work?

Comment: Try logging all gestures and printing them out to see whether they are working at all. Also, you might be nulling `Current_Start` and `Current_End` between recording last gesture path and checking if it has been completed. If so, you'll have to rethink that.

Comment: I do have a list of the latest touch points, but that's using TouchCollection.Position, rather than the gestures. I have put breakpoints during Gesture Sampling, and there are gestures being read.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the onmousedown and onmouseup events to get the start and end points and go from there.